# how to find if the text is highlighted in single-line textbox (either with mouse or with keyboard)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how do we find, if the text is highlighted in a single-line text-box (either with mouse or with keyboard), using jquery?

Assuming text-box is:

```
<input id="input1" type="text"/>
```

I am trying to do this with id-attribute. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something similar to what you want but need some changes:

http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html

**Demo:**

http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/05/get-selected-text-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow already has a post that answers to your issue.

See on post [jQuery: get the highlighted text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5379120/1853864)